# Weird UITableView behaviour while tapping on a cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have worked with `UITableView`s in iOS before but something really weird seems to be happening this time. I need a push a new `UIViewController` on selecting a `UITableViewCell`. Everything is working fine except, sometimes, when I pop back to the `UIViewController` that contains the `UITableView` and try and select a different `UITableViewCell` than the previous one, it automatically selects the `UITableViewCell` that was tapped on previously. I know it may sound funny to some of you but it's happening to me and has been troubling me for more than a day now. Any help would be hugely helpful. I know it's something really silly but I can't seem to spot it.

Here is how the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' looks like -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"row - %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    Notification *obj = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (obj.post.post_id) {
        FeedViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postsView"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        vc.postID = obj.post.post_id;
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UserProfileViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"userProfile"];
        vc.username = obj.user.username;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    }
}
```

After debugging for hours, I was able to see that, upon coming back, the intended `UITableViewCell` never gets highlighted in the default manner it's supposed to and as soon as the touch is released, the "old" `UITableViewCell` gets selected and performs its action.

**UPDATE**

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` goes like this -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NotificationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notificationCell"];
Notification *obj = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.cellIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
cell.delegate = self;
cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userImage.frame.size.width / 2.0f;
[cell.userImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.user.photo]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
cell.timeLabel.text = obj.timestamp;
cell.descriptionLabel.text = [@"@" stringByAppendingString:[[obj.user.username stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:obj.message]];

cell.descriptionLabel.userHandleLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
    NSLog(@"User tapped %@", string);
    [self didTapOnCallout:string];
};

cell.descriptionLabel.hashtagLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
    NSLog(@"Hashtag tapped %@", string);
    [self didTapOnHashTag:string];
};

cell.descriptionLabel.urlLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
    NSLog(@"URL tapped %@", string);
    [self didTapOnURL:string];
};

return cell;
}
```

I am making use of KILabel to listen for taps on URLs and hashtags.

Comment: Update your question with the code.

Comment: Updated the code @RajeshkumarR

Comment: Do you have a `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` in the view controller?  (I have sometimes made errors with those names.)

Comment: @PhillipMills no

Comment: show `cellForRowAt indexPath` method also.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a bug in the KILabel library I was using to detect taps on hashtags and URLs.

Head over here if you are facing a similar issue - https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel/issues/57